# Spring cloud dataflow DestinationReslutionException when running sample source

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have problem with running sample spring-cloud-dataflow source app. Application exits with code 0 (and it should be working). I debugged it and noticed following exception being thrown:

```
DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'output'
```

I was follownig the getting started guide http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_getting_started and I can't get it worked. 
What I have done:
- I have zookeeper working;
- I have kafka working;

The code:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;

@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class SampleSource {

    @InboundChannelAdapter(Source.OUTPUT)
    public String greet() {
        return "hello world " + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleSourceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(SampleSourceApplication.class, args)) {
        }
    }
}
```

And pom:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Commandline arguments: --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=test

I can give more details about the Exception:

```
org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'output' in the BeanFactory.; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source': Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties': Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2ef14fe has been closed already
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class `SampleSource` isn't imported by the main application.
Are you sure the `SampleSource` class is in the same package as that of `SampleSourceApplication`?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same package. What is more, I added a breakpoint on greet() method and it gets executed. I stepped in and message is prepared correctly, but further there is exception DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'output'. I assume there is a problem with communication?

Comment: Looking at your code again, what is `DisSampleSourceApplication` in the main method? I guess that needs to be `SampleSourceApplication`

Comment: Yes, this was mistake when copying code to this question. In my code class names matches. Fixed.

Comment: I added more exception details to my question.